# d3 javascript change range of the y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axes

I'm a beginner with d3 javascript and I don't know how to change the y axis on this grouped bar chart:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 Data + code can be found here

This is the code of the site & the data of the grouped bar chart:

```
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis() //creating a generic axis function//
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("gender_ratio.csv", function(error, data) {
  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Perioden"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]*1000};  });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Perioden; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var Perioden = svg.selectAll(".Perioden")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Perioden) + ",0)"; });

  Perioden.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```

Data:

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
TX,2027307,3277946,1420518,2454721,7017731,5656528,2472223
NY,1208495,2141490,1058031,1999120,5355235,5120254,2607672
FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
PA,737462,1345341,679201,1203944,3157759,3414001,1910571
```

Comment: What do you want to change about the y axis? If you're struggling to get to grips with d3 for graphing, you might like to take a look at c3.js or dimple.js which are chart-specific libraries built on top of d3 that are easier to learn.

Comment: This line sets the **domain** of the y axis:  `y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);`, if you want your values to go from 1650 to 1700, its just `y.domain([1650, 1700]);`

Comment: @mark I mean I need to change the X axes sorry.

Comment: In the example you link to the x-axis is ordinal meaning discrete text-based values.  Is your axis really like that or is it numeric?  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Mark The x-axis is numeric so i try to change the x-axes value to 1650 till 1700

Answer (score 2):

If your x-axis is regular old numeric data, you should be using a `linear` scale not an `ordinal`.  Ordinal is meant for discrete values (think a, b, c or x, y, z or tom, dick, harry) while linear is meant for continuous data (think 1,2,3 or 50, 100, 150):

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .range([0, width])
     .domain([1650, 1700]);
```

In `d3` speak, range is the **pixel** span of your data (from min to max), while **domain** is the user-space span of your data (the min and max of your data values).  The scale that's returned then maps your user space data to it's pixel space position.

Below is a **heavily commented** example of a simple `d3` bar graph:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

  // sample data with x and y values
  // d3 likes arrays of objects
  var data = [
    {
      x: 1660,
      y: 1
    },{
      x: 1670,
      y: 2
    },{
      x: 1680,
      y: 3
    },{
      x: 1690,
      y: 4
    }
  ];

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0,width]) // our pixel span
  .domain([1650, 1700]); // our user space data span

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]) // same thing as x, pixel span
    .domain([0,5]); // user space space

  // marry the scale to the axis
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

  // set up our svg tag
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // draw x axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  // draw y axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
      
  // get a nice bar width
  // it is the width of our axis divided by the number of ticks
  var barWidth = (width / xAxis.ticks()[0]);

  // draw the bars
  var state = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) - (barWidth / 2); }) // center it on tick
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); }) // y is the top of the bar
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); }); // and height goes to axis

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If it is a text based scale so a .csv file. What I need to change then in the code of mine

Comment: It's ordinal sorry, so the data is in a .csv file.